# I need a Regex, that which accepts only a String(with only Alphabets and Numbers) with spaces allowed at the start and end, but not in between?

Tags: java, regex

`^[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z0-9\f\t]$`I tried using this, but it is not accepting strings with a space at the end. I am trying to make some server side validation using Regex for this case in Java.

Comment: An option consists to trim the string before.

Comment: How come the regex you tried doesn't match your description - is it supposed to allow a single tab at the end but not at the start? Can the string not be empty? Does "spaces" mean listerally space characters or any whitespace characters? [`^\ *[[:alnum:]]+\ *$`](https://regex101.com/r/eA3gO5/1) will do what you describe..

Comment: It should not allow any white spaces(horizontal tabs) in between and should allow at the start and at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add optional spaces at the beginning and at the end:

```
^\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+\s*$
```

Comment: I need to include that in a Java Code, so when I did that I see an error saying "Invalid escape sequence". Is there a way to get rid of that ?

Comment: @vamshi Well, as Java developer you should know better (as I'm .NET), but I assume dubbling backslash should do the trick.
"^\\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+\\s*$"

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

 at Reg.main(Reg.java:14).  //I see this error

Comment: Did you use this string? "^\\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+\\s*$" Copy and paste it into your code

Comment: @vamshi Accepting the answer will be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
\s+[\w\d]+\s+
```

Comment: \w allows underscores and also includes digits

Comment: While this regex may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.